# Why does adding these numbers equal NaN in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to loop through this object and add up the values for each person. Why does this return `NaN`?

```js
var result = {
  "alex": {
    "1": 9.333333333333334,
    "2": 7.666666666666666,
    "3": 8.666666666666668,
    "4": 8.666666666666668,
    "5": 9.666666666666668,
    "6": 9,
    "7": 10,
    "8": 10,
    "9": 9.333333333333334,
    "10": 8.333333333333334,
    "11": 10,
    "12": 9.333333333333334
  },
  "frank": {
    "1": 9.666666666666668,
    "2": 10,
    "3": 9.333333333333334,
    "4": 9.333333333333334,
    "5": 9.333333333333334,
    "6": 9.333333333333334,
    "7": 8.666666666666666,
    "8": 9,
    "9": 9.333333333333334,
    "10": 8.666666666666668,
    "11": 7.666666666666666,
    "12": 8.666666666666668
  }
}


var res1, res2;
for (var key in result.alex) {
  res1 += parseInt(result.alex[key]);
}
for (var key in result.frank) {
  res2 += parseInt(result.frank[key]);
}

console.log("Res1: " + res1);
console.log("Res2: " + res2);
```

If I remove the `+` then I get a valid number back, although, it's only a single number obviously.

Whats the issue here?

Comment: Think hard, what is the value of `res1` just before the first `+=` in your code?

Comment: you're not initiating the variables resulting in `undefined += `

Comment: `var res1 = 0;`

Comment: @Teemu facepalm moment. Since you were effectively the first to answer *though indirect*, add it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Since this is a duplicate, should I remove this question?

Comment: @ProEvilz You can't, it has upvoted answers. All the dups are not bad, it's easier to find an answer, when there are more than a single post.

Answer (score 3):

Your variables are not initialized to 0. You are adding number to un-initialized variable.

Initialize res1, and res2 as below.

```
var res1 = 0, res2=0;
```

```js
var result = {
  "alex": {
    "1": 9.333333333333334,
    "2": 7.666666666666666,
    "3": 8.666666666666668,
    "4": 8.666666666666668,
    "5": 9.666666666666668,
    "6": 9,
    "7": 10,
    "8": 10,
    "9": 9.333333333333334,
    "10": 8.333333333333334,
    "11": 10,
    "12": 9.333333333333334
  },
  "frank": {
    "1": 9.666666666666668,
    "2": 10,
    "3": 9.333333333333334,
    "4": 9.333333333333334,
    "5": 9.333333333333334,
    "6": 9.333333333333334,
    "7": 8.666666666666666,
    "8": 9,
    "9": 9.333333333333334,
    "10": 8.666666666666668,
    "11": 7.666666666666666,
    "12": 8.666666666666668
  }
}


var res1 = 0, res2=0;
for (var key in result.alex) {
  res1 += parseInt(result.alex[key]);
}
for (var key in result.frank) {
  res2 += parseInt(result.frank[key]);
}

console.log("Res1: " + res1);
console.log("Res2: " + res2);
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because res1 and res2 are undefined, just define it to 0

```js
var result = {
  "alex": {
    "1": 9.333333333333334,
    "2": 7.666666666666666,
    "3": 8.666666666666668,
    "4": 8.666666666666668,
    "5": 9.666666666666668,
    "6": 9,
    "7": 10,
    "8": 10,
    "9": 9.333333333333334,
    "10": 8.333333333333334,
    "11": 10,
    "12": 9.333333333333334
  },
  "frank": {
    "1": 9.666666666666668,
    "2": 10,
    "3": 9.333333333333334,
    "4": 9.333333333333334,
    "5": 9.333333333333334,
    "6": 9.333333333333334,
    "7": 8.666666666666666,
    "8": 9,
    "9": 9.333333333333334,
    "10": 8.666666666666668,
    "11": 7.666666666666666,
    "12": 8.666666666666668
  }
}


var res1=0, res2=0;
for (var key in result.alex) {
  res1 += parseInt(result.alex[key]);
}
for (var key in result.frank) {
  res2 += parseInt(result.frank[key]);
}

console.log("Res1: " + res1);
console.log("Res2: " + res2);
```

Comment: Thanks, got it, But they are defined, they just don't have a value assigned to them.

Comment: they are declared not defined

Comment: @ProEvilz then they are 'undefined'

Comment: @marvel308 Yeah, sorry, that is what I was trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

Proeprties `res1` and `res2` are `undefined`. If you are adding some number to `undefined` result will be `NaN`. So you need to initialize that properties with `0` value.

```
var res1 = 0, res2 = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks, got it, But they are defined, they just don't have a value assigned to them.

Comment: if you declare variable, but do not assign any value to it, the value of it will be `undefined`

Comment: no they're not @ProEvilz `undefined` is a special type/value in javascript

Comment: @ProEvilz Exactly, how do you add a number to something you don't know?

Comment: Ok, I stand corrected. I figured since it's wrote down it would be technically defined... as in defined/wrote down. You're right.

Comment: As mentioned above, I was trying to say they are *declared*, they just don't have a value *defined*

Answer (score 0):

Initialize res1 and res2 to 0, as you do a += afterwards.

```js
var result = {
  "alex": {
    "1": 9.333333333333334,
    "2": 7.666666666666666,
    "3": 8.666666666666668,
    "4": 8.666666666666668,
    "5": 9.666666666666668,
    "6": 9,
    "7": 10,
    "8": 10,
    "9": 9.333333333333334,
    "10": 8.333333333333334,
    "11": 10,
    "12": 9.333333333333334
  },
  "frank": {
    "1": 9.666666666666668,
    "2": 10,
    "3": 9.333333333333334,
    "4": 9.333333333333334,
    "5": 9.333333333333334,
    "6": 9.333333333333334,
    "7": 8.666666666666666,
    "8": 9,
    "9": 9.333333333333334,
    "10": 8.666666666666668,
    "11": 7.666666666666666,
    "12": 8.666666666666668
  }
}


var res1 = 0, res2 = 0;
for (var key in result.alex) {
  res1 += parseInt(result.alex[key]);
}
for (var key in result.frank) {
  res2 += parseInt(result.frank[key]);
}

console.log("Res1: " + res1);
console.log("Res2: " + res2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `res1` and `res2` is undefiend. You should declair it like `var res1=0, res2=0;`